# Swing Panel Question

Tags: swing

Ok, so I've been pulling my hair out over this all day. I cannot get my panels to resize. I add a panel to anything.. a frame, a content pane, and It wont .. "force" setBounds for some strange reason.

```
Container pane = window.getContentPane();
JPanel calendarPanel = new JPanel(); 
pane.add(calendarPanel); 
calendarPanel.setBounds(0,0, 320, 335);
```

note that window is of JFrame. Any suggestions to sizing a panel would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, it sounds like you need to look at [layout managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). Some layout managers honour the requested or preferred sizes of components, others don't.

By default a `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` as the layout manager. When you add your calendar panel above without supplying constraints, it assumes you want the panel centred. Anything centred in a `BorderLayout` takes up all the available space, no matter what you set the bounds of the component to.

For an immediate fix to your problem, set the layout manager to `null`:

```
Container pane = window.getContentPane();
pane.setLayout( null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the Layout of the parent component? I think the FlowLayout leaves the panel to his natural size.

```
component.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
```

EDIT: see Ash's post